# wxpython, what to bind an application wide mouse event to

Tags: wxpython

hey.. i have a panel (lets call it mainpanel) with a couple of panels in it and other widgets. i need to know what to bind the wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN to in order for it to fire an event for clicks anywhere in mainpanel and its children. e.g. if i click on a textctrl in mainpanel i want it to pick that up aswell. binding to mainpanel doesnt work. please help i really need to find a solution to this its making me mad!
p.s. binding everychild to the wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN is not an option i have hundreds of children i really dont want to go that route

Answer (score 0):

Text controls eat mouse clicks so you may just want to catch the focus event for them. I think the rest should work though.

Comment: my problem is if i bind to mainpanel only clicks in that panel are picked up not in its children. any children widgets dont work.. even panels. seems i need to bind to each one seperately

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you need this functionality.

Comment: i am trying to make my own listbox. i want my own unique looking list box which has images and text and buttons within the colums and rows. so im making it with panels. now for the selection process of selecting a panel in the listbox i have a problem because in the panel there are other panels and texts and buttons etc. so i want something so that if i click on any of the children in this panel it will trigger an event where ill get the main panel that i want highlighted to show its selected

Comment: Ok. Well, I've never created a custom control. Try posting on the official wxPython group. There are several guys there that have created custom widgets there: http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/topics?pli=1